# CSS Grid : dynamic dependend min-width?

Tags: css, css-grid, column-width

i have the following structure :

- root grid

  - grid1
  - grid2
  - grid3

I define the columns : repeat(5 1fr)

the problem is that because the content they have different widths.
Is there a way somehow to pick the largest element width and set it as min-width to the other 2 grids.

Something like this /pseudo code/:

```
repeat(5 minmax(max(grid1.cells.width,grid2.cells.width,grid3.cells.width)), 1fr))
```

or in case i know which grid will be widest :

```
repeat(5 minmax(grid2.cells.width,  1fr))
```

---

this is very hacky non automatic solution:

```
 let min_width = window.getComputedStyle(grid2.children[0]).width
 grid1.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${grid1_ncols}, minmax(${min_width}, 1fr))`
```

a better one ??

Comment: Could you explain a bit more why you must have grid not flex?

Comment: Whenever possible, you need to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: because i'm doing sort of a table with independent dynamic data sub-grids .. and Table was not suitable